# A question about angular momentum and angular velocity of a symmetrical body

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

I know that a symmetrical body rotating round a fixed axis, at a constant angular velocity, has the vector angular momentum and the vector angular velocity parallel, but if the angular velocity isn't constant, will the 2 vectors be parallel?

Comment: By not constant you mean the magnitude changing, or the direction, or both?

Comment: I meant that only the magnitude will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fixed axis is the axis of symmetry (a principal axis), and if the angular velocity vector is fixed in direction along that axis, then if the angular speed is changed the angular momentum vector and angular velocity vector remain parallel.